# Drupal 6 Views - how to sort on # of comments for a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm using Drupal (6) Views (6.2) to render a list of items, one of which is the number of comments that the particular item has (along with another calculated field for the star rating for the item).

I have been banging my head trying to add an ORDER BY that would be very simple with a plain SQL query - namely the count of comments. I want to sort by star rating  and then count of comments.

I have tried using a calculated field, but it always comes up empty.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have Drupal 6.25 (there were some updates related to this in 6.25 release).
2. Create a View on node table.
3. add new sort criteria: Node: Comment count.

Not sure what you meant by star ratings though. If you want to get FiveStar or Rate module's data (Voting API's data actually), add a relationship to voting results first.